Term for gun control advocate who respects the second amendment
What would be the term for someone who is not particularly libertarian with respect to gun ownership but still respects the Second Amendment’s existence?

What does "respect the amendment" mean exactly in this context? The term could be pragmatic, because amendments are difficult to change but maybe also blind believer or many other things.

This Q is probably better asked at English.Stackexchange

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron

It would be best to simply describe the person's position in a sentence or two.
There is no consensus term for a person who recognizes and respects that the law is X, but simultaneously advocates for the law to be more restrictive or permissive within the constitutional limits or to alter the constitutional limits on X.
In the field of jurisprudence (theory of law), the term "legal positivist" would be appropriate: this is someone who recognizes that what the law is is dependent on social facts, and is a separate question from what law should be. But this is likely too general a term to be helpfully descriptive for you.
Most (all?) people hold this view for some values of X: gun control, tax, speed limits, tort law, drug prohibition, copyright, patent, etc.
Because there is so much variation in peoples' level of support or disagreement with a particular law or constitutional limit and the kind of reforms for which they would advocate, reducing this all to a single term would be obscuring. Even your attempt to summarize the position as "respect[ing] the Second Amendment" has left ambiguity.

At least notionally this is the position of "common sense" gun control advocates, that people should be allowed to own some weapons for some purposes but not other weapons based on a balancing of use for whatever their chosen legitimate purposes are and whatever their chosen risk of illegitimate purposes are.  So more succinctly they think the people have a right to keep and bear arms but not all arms, based on a "common sense" balancing test.

"Common Sense" gun control is political rhetoric and branding for promoting gun control legislation. It is not its own group or organization. There are a variety of different advocacy groups that promote "Common Sense" gun control. Its associated with legislative points. Its not a term associated with people.
